# Why I can't parse JSON in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

JSON contains one object:

```
results[0] = { 'MAX(id)': 1 }
```

And this code doesn't work:

```
var text = results[0];
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
console.log(obj.MAX(id));
```

Comment: Your `results[0]` is already an object, not a JSON string, so no need to parse it. Then you should use `obj['Max(id)']` because it's a string, not a method.

Answer (score 1):

`results[0]` is already an object type

You can parse only from string to object like this:

```
JSON.parse('{ "MAX(id)": 1 }');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your object is already a JSON. You don't need to parse it.
To access `MAX(id)` property, you can use [] notation as follows:

```
results[0] = { 'MAX(id)': 1 };
console.log(results[0]['MAX(id)']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your result[0] is a real javascript object. JSON.parse transforms text into objects, so you can't parse other objects with it.

Answer (score 1):

```js
    var results = { 'MAX(id)': 1 };
    //var text = results;
    //var obj = JSON.parse(text);
    alert(results['MAX(id)']);
```